# Fishing Poisson Process

Tags: poisson-process

Jack likes to go fishing. While waiting for the fish to bite, he formulates the following model for the process: fish bite according to a Poisson process with intensity 4 bites per hour. Biting fish are caught independently, and on average only one in two times.

**My solutions so far:**

N(2) = # of fish biting during 2 hours = Poisson(8)

M(2) = # of fish caught during two hours = Poisson(4)

**a) What is the probability that six fish bite during the first two hours?**

P(N(2) = 6) is what we have to solve for.

**b) What is the probability that he fails to catch any fish during the first two hours?**

P(M(2) = 0) = $e^{-4}$ = 0.018 = 1.8% chance he catches no fish during the first two hours.

**c) What is the probability that, during the first two hours, six fish bite and two of these
are caught?**

P(M(2) = 2|N(2) = 6)

I need help solving part a and c as I am not sure how to properly solve for these probabilities. I am confident in my solution for part b. Thanks!